# Drawing tangents to curves by hand

Tags: graphing-functions, tangent-line

Recently I was doing a practice test that asked to draw a tangent on the graph at x = -1.5 and calculate it's gradient. However when drawing the tangent I found the gradient to be extremely inaccurate despite my line seeming to only touch the graph at a single point.

Is there any tips or tricks to accurately draw tangents on graphs by hand?

Comment: Sometimes it's more accurate to estimate the [osculating circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle) at a point $P$ (the circle that resembles the most locally at your curve in that point) ; then joining the center of the circle to point $P$ gives you a convenient approximate normal line (without having to draw an approximate tangent line beforehand).

Comment: @JeanMarie. One more thing I forgot ! Very nice way to do it